# How do I loop through scraped data, and export the results to a CSV file, with each dictionary as a new row in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am fairly new to coding, and was messing around with how to export scraped data to CSV.

**Problem**

My script goes through a set of similar pages and extracts data from each page and stores it to a dictionary. Each dictionary has the same keys, but different values, i.e. each scraped page has a dictionary associated with it, although the keys are the same.

I would like to export the individual dictionaries, once scraped, to a CSV file, with each dictionary occupying one row, but I am struggling to figure out the syntax.

Do I need to create a dictionary of dictionaries? Or can each scraped dictionary be appended to a single CSV file?

Cheers,

This is what I have so far:

```css
papers = []
urls  = []
dict = {'Topics':0,'Link':0, 'Heading':0,"Summary Intro":0,"Summary Text":0, "Date":0}


for i in range(1,4): 
        
    url = str(a) + str(i) + str(c) 
    urls.append(url)
pprint(urls) 

for url in urls:
    print url    
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    soup.find_all('div', class_="bp-paper-item commons")
    for link in soup.find_all('a', class_="title"):
        pdflist = []            
        pdflink1 = 'https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk' 
        pdflink2 = link.get('href')
        pdflink = pdflink1 + pdflink2
        x = str(pdflink)
        dict['Link'] = x
        pdfsoup = urllib2.urlopen(x).read() #opens link to the pdf
        pdfdata = BeautifulSoup(pdfsoup)
        for date in pdfdata.find_all('div', id="bp-published-date"):
            dict['Date'] = date.text.encode('utf').strip()
        for heading in pdfdata.find_all('h1'):
            dict['Heading'] = heading.text.encode('utf').strip()             
        for topics in pdfdata.find_all('div', id="bp-summary-metadata"):           
            dict['Topics'] = topics.text.encode('utf').strip()                  
        for downloadlink in pdfdata.find_all('div',id="bp-summary-fullreport"):
            dl = downloadlink.find('a', id="bp-summary-fullreport-link")
            print dl
        toCSV = [dict]
        keys = toCSV[0].keys()
        with open('UKPARL.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
            dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
            dict_writer.writeheader()
            dict_writer.writerows(toCSV)
```

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: Added the code from my attempt.